# Concatenate dataframe with difrent dimension

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data that are stored in three different data frames with different lengths. Below you can see my data :

```
df<-data.frame(  
  retail_seling_price=c(10),
  quantity_10=c(1000)
)

df


df1<-data.frame(  
  retail_seling_price=c(100,200,300),
  quantity_18=c(1000,2000,3000)
)

df1

df2<-data.frame(  
  retail_seling_price=c(100,200,300,400),
  quantity_18=c(1000,2000,3000,0)
)

df2
```

So now I want to merge all these data frames into one data frame, as in the pic shown below.

[image]

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your `df2` supposed to have `quantity_20` instead of `quantity_18`? If so (fixed for below), this is a combination of `full_join` (for each pair of frames) and `Reduce` on a list of frames to do the same for an arbitrary number of frames.

```r
library(dplyr)
Reduce(function(a, b) full_join(a, b, by = "retail_seling_price"),
       list(df, df1, df2)) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ coalesce(., 0)))
#   retail_seling_price quantity_10 quantity_18 quantity_20
# 1                  10        1000           0           0
# 2                 100           0        1000        1000
# 3                 200           0        2000        2000
# 4                 300           0        3000        3000
# 5                 400           0           0           0
```

Frankly, we don't need `dplyr` for this, it's handy to use for fixing all of the `NA` values introduced by the initial join:

```r
Reduce(function(a, b) full_join(a, b, by = "retail_seling_price"),
       list(df, df1, df2))
#   retail_seling_price quantity_10 quantity_18 quantity_20
# 1                  10        1000          NA          NA
# 2                 100          NA        1000        1000
# 3                 200          NA        2000        2000
# 4                 300          NA        3000        3000
# 5                 400          NA          NA           0
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a another `dplyr` approach using `bind_rows`:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(df, df1, df2) %>% 
  group_by(retail_seling_price) %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

```
 retail_seling_price quantity_10 quantity_18 quantity_20
                <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1                  10        1000           0           0
2                 100           0        1000        1000
3                 200           0        2000        2000
4                 300           0        3000        3000
5                 400           0           0           0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 rbindlist(list(df, df1, df2), fill = TRUE)[,
   lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = retail_seling_price]
   retail_seling_price quantity_10 quantity_18
1:                  10        1000           0
2:                 100           0        2000
3:                 200           0        4000
4:                 300           0        6000
5:                 400           0           0
```